# Что за словообразовательный элемент "з" в словах: боязнь, неприязнь, болезнь, жизнь?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, морфемика

Что это за странный словообразовательный элемент "з", почему он присутствует только в этих (боя**з**нь, неприя**з**нь, боле**з**нь, жи**з**нь) словах?

Comment: @Galina В правилах вроде написано, что основной приток аудитории должен быть извне (сомневаюсь, что с таким заголовком у этой страницы будут хоть какие-то шансы быть найденной на просторах рунета). Слова из заголовков, расположенные после 50-х символов не получают никакого "веса" .

Comment: Тогда оформляйте сами - по-человечески. И без ошибок. Чтобы не приходилось обнаруживать Ваши вопросы в предложенном к удалению/закрытию.

Comment: Почему Вы не благодарите ответивших (клик по верхнему треугольнику, клик по галочке внизу)? Вам и отвечать не интересно: ответ брошен как в омут. Тишина...

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас это нерегулярный суффикс -зн(ь), он образует имена от глагольных корней: жизнь, боязнь, приязнь, болезнь. СЗ: ‘отвлеченное действие, состояние или отношение’.